# Evento onClick com Android Preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Tenho algumas preferências dentro do `PreferenceScreen` no arquivo `xml/preferences.xml`. São alguns itens no qual preciso que sejam mostrados para o usuário. Veja abaixo:

```
<Preference
    android:key="pref_key_info"
    android:title="@string/info" />
<Preference
    android:key="pref_key_version"
    android:summary="@string/info_version_sumary"
    android:title="@string/info_version" />
```

Quando clicar no primeiro item, no caso o `<preference>` com chave `pref_key_info`, quero que abra uma tela de diálogo com algumas informações.

Como colocar um evento de `onClick` no `<preference>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro passo é definir o `android:key` para o item de preferência. Neste caso já possui o `pref_key_info` no item. Logo depois no seu `Fragment` que extende o `PreferenceFragment` deve-se criar uma instancia usando o método `findPreference()`. Por final, bastar usar o método `setOnPreferenceClickListener()` para inserir o evento ao clicar na preferência específica. Veja abaixo como deve ficar seu código.

```
Preference info = (Preference) findPreference("pref_key_info");
info.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
       // aqui pode inserir a janela do dialogo

       return false;
   }
});
```

Mais detalhes sobre [Android Preferences na documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html?hl=pt-br).